# PDOException error in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am getting the following error message when executing my query

```
[2/2] DBALException: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT DISTINCT s0_.id AS id0, s0_. AS 1 FROM shop s0_ WHERE s0_.isLocked = ? ORDER BY s0_.owner_id DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0' with params [0]:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS 1 FROM shop s0_ WHERE s0_.isLocked = 0 ORDER BY s0_.owner_' at line 1   +

[1/2] PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS 1 FROM shop s0_ WHERE s0_.isLocked = 0 ORDER BY s0_.owner_' at line 1
```

Is this supposed to be a query error or is this something else ? Because it seems that my query is legit.

Comment: s0_. AS 1 ?? where is field name

Comment: Perhaps you have forgotten to specify the column `s0_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT s0_.id AS id0, s0_. AS 1
```

It is supposed to be a query error. You are selecting the unique id's from table s0_ and a field with no name of that same table, but a field can't have no name.

You should add a fieldname, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s0_.id AS id0, s0_.FIELDNAME AS `1`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT s0_.id AS id0, s0_. AS `1`
```

wrap 1 in ``

And the missing field name from comments above...